# Let P be a tetrahedron, and let vector (V, E, F) = (4, 6, 4) represent the number of vertices, edges, and faces of P.

Tags: polyhedra, visualization

What are the possible (V, E, F) vectors that can be obtained by stacking pyramids over faces of P? Justify this in depth.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @YiFan I really do not know where to begin with this one.

Comment: I would start with adding one pyramid.